# How do I find out the name of the SSID I'm connected to from the command line?

Tags: networking, wireless, command-line

Neither `iwconfig` nor `iwlist` seem to be able to do this for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Run `nm-tool | grep \*`. That should show just the line with the SSID you are connected to.

Edit: The `nm-tool` utility had ceased to exist, so in 16.04 and newer releases, please use any of the methods suggested by my esteemed colleagues below.

For example: `nmcli -t -f active,ssid dev wifi | egrep '^yes' | cut -d\' -f2` works well.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed.  To get just the name:nm-tool |grep --only-matching '\*[^ ][^:]*' |sed 's/^\*//'

Comment: `nmcli -t -f active,ssid dev wifi` is easier to parse. The ssid is unfortunately encapsulated in some useless quotes though.

Comment: Or: `nmcli -t -f active,ssid dev wifi | egrep '^yes' | cut -d\' -f2` (which will work as long as the SSID doesn't contain any `'` characters)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10: `$ nm-tool | grep \*
No command 'nm-tool' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dm-tool' from package 'lightdm' (main)
nm-tool: command not found` Scott's command works though

Comment: `$ nmcli -t -f active,ssid dev wifi | egrep '^yes' | cut -d\: -f2` is the command I just used on Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 166):

`iwgetid` provides the ssid

`iwgetid -r` gives just the name.

In a Bash script try something like `myssid=$(iwgetid -r)` to put it in a variable

Comment: Thanks! Looks much better than the commonly recommended iw/iwlan+sed/grep solutions.

Answer (score 32):

Although the question has already been answered, the **iwconfig** tool *does* display the ESSID of the currently connected Wifi network. Perhaps it does not work with connections managed through **NetworkManager** but it works with interfaces managed through **ifup/ifdown**:

```
iwconfig | grep wlan0
```

lists:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ahoi"
```

Comment: Typing `iwconfig` only can do the purpose too :-) thanks for sharing this command :-)

Answer (score 18):

None of the prior answers worked for me unfortunately.  I was however able to get the details via

```
$ sudo iw dev wlan0 info
```

and got

```
Interface wlan0
    ifindex 5
    wdev 0x1
    addr **:**:*:*:*:*
    ssid *****
    type AP
    wiphy 0
    channel 2 (2417 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2417 MHz
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/256074/determine-the-wireless-network-name-from-command-line-in-linux/968207#968207) to extract the SSID from the output.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the `iw` tool (from the **iw** package) to obtain the WiFi link parameters which includes the currently associated SSID - e.g for wlan0:

```
iw dev wlan0 link
```

Answer (score 6):

```
nmcli -t -f name connection show --active
```

shows the same output without listing all available SSIDs in vicinity so without delay.
if more network interfaces are available and active can be parsed by interface name like so:

```
nmcli -t -f name,device connection show --active | grep wlp3s0 | cut -d\: -f1
```

Comment: Useful for users who use networkmanager (like me)

Answer (score 3):

simply use this command to get only the ssid "NAME"

```
iw dev wlan0 info | grep ssid | awk '{print $2}'
```

Where `wlan0` is the interface for your Wi-Fi card. Check it in `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`.

The output is only the "ssid name" of the network you connected...

Comment: using sudo to get this, especially for a script, is silly.